# How much hard drive space should I allocate to Ubuntu for a 1tb hard drive?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I was given a 1tb hard drive and I want to place ubuntu since I would have to start using it for school and I have 16 GB ram. I want to allocate the entire drive for ubuntu since I don't need the extra space. Is there a reason I shouldn't, or should?

Comment: I allocate 30GB for the system partition, but I only use 1/4 of them.

Comment: If you only use one partition, if you ever have to format and re-install, you lose all your data.

Comment: this is true if you don't have your home on a separate partition but for a new user it becomes more complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any reason for not using the whole drive. If you don't plan on dual booting or anything like that .. then you might as well use the hole drive.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a fan of linux/ubuntu and you plan to stay on it for life - that means that you will not need to install other OS (operating system), you will play games only in ubuntu / wine - then use whole space for it.

You can always add another (smaller) HDD if you would need to install another OS, or you can install another OS into VirtualBox.

On the other hand if you will need some other OS for example Windows because of gaming, or use some specific graphic programs that do not run on Ubuntu then I would leave some space free (windows installation = at least 30gb, games = additional 50-70gb just to be sure). You can always mount this NTFS space into linux to have it visible in Ubuntu too.